# vshost32.exe stops working when connecting to Access database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, oledb, ms-access-2016

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and connecting it to MS Access 2016. My system is working without any error but when I try to click the search button the vshost32.exe always stops working.

Here is my code:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication4
{
public partial class SalesInventory : Form
{

    public SalesInventory()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SearchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string source = @"Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Irma\\Documents\\project.accbd;Persist Securit Info= False";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(source);
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string str = "Select * FROM Products WHERE Product_Name LIKE '%" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%'";
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(str, conn);

            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            ds.Clear();
            da.Fill(ds);
            GrindView.DataSource = ds;
            conn.Close();

        }
        else
        {
            string str = "Select * FROM Products WHERE Product_Name LIKE '%" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%'";
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(str, conn);

            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            ds.Clear();
            da.Fill(ds);
            GrindView.DataSource = ds;
            conn.Close();

        }
    }
}
}
```

Even with this code vshost32.exe stops working:

```
    private void AddBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Irma\\Documents\\project.accbd;Persist Security Info= False";

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Insert into Product([Product_Name]) VALUES (@ProdName)");
        command.Connection = conn;
        conn.Open();
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdName", ProdNameText.Text);


            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Added");
                conn.Close();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Insert into product_Fields([Product_Name],[Description],[Category],[Quantity],[Price],[Supplier_Name]) VALUES (@prodName,@Description,@Category,@Quantity,@Price,@Supplier_Name)");
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prodName", ProdNameText.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", DescriptionComboBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", CategoryComboBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", QuantityBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", PriceBox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Supplier_Name", SupplierNameText.Text);
                }
                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Added");
                    conn.Close();

                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error");
                    conn.Close();
                }
                }

            catch
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Error");
                conn.Close();

            }
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Data Connection Failed");
            this.Close();
        }

        }
```

Comment: Try using ODBC data objects instead of OleDb ones. (OleDb is very very old.) All you need to do is find and replace OleDb with Odbc.

Comment: @simonatrcl does it have the same use of command and should i put it on using system.data?

Comment: and do u think it will have any complication with my current codes if just change them?

Comment: Yep. Change from using System.Data.OleDb to using System.Data.Odbc, and then create the OdbcConnection, OdbcCommand, etc etc and it should be OK. Worth a try, anyway.

Comment: PS I don't remember if ODBC has an AddWithParameters function. If not, it's easy enough to adapt your code.